# Proper way of using who and whose clause at the same time

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses

In my writing, I ended up writing the following sentence:

> It benefits both students who perform the review and whose work is
>   reviewed.

I wonder if there is any structural issues in the way I used `who` and `whose`. For example, I wonder if it would be better to say:

> It benefits both the student who performed the review and the student
>   whose work was reviewed.

Any ideas? Please also recommend me if I should use present tense (1) or past tense (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version makes sense. In the first version it sounds like both students perform the review, which you obviously don't want to say.

You probably could say it like that:

> It benefits those students who perform the review and those, whose work is reviewed.

What tense you use depends on the context, but I think both would work. If you use present tense the benefits apply as they review/work. If you use past tense the benefits still apply even if the performing/working is over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you avoid **'both'** on purpose, do you think it is not very necessary? Also, why a comma is necessary just after the second **'those'**? Additionally, do you think **'those, whose work'** should be treated as plural?

Comment: You're right, you can add the “both“, didn't avoid it on purpose;) I used a comma, because I think that before 'whose' you have to do so (also before 'which'). Yes, 'those, whose work' is plural, as we said 'those' and refer to two students (at least).

Comment: Thanks! then, you mean it should be **those, whose work are/were reviewed**

Comment: As you refer to 'work', it would be 'is/was reviewed'. 'Those, whose work' refers to the students, but 'is/was reviewed' refers to 'work'. Using 'are/were reviewed' you would refer to the students, which wouldn't make sense in this context. Work itself is not plural.